# Cannot save a DateTime object to a datetime field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, redbean

Here is my database schema for my MySQL database:

```
create table noticia 
(
    id int,
    imagen varchar(255),
    fecha datetime,
    titulo varchar(255),
    url varchar(255),
    descripcion varchar(255),
    contenido text
)
```

I'm using RedBeanPHP as my ORM to save the information to a database. Here is where I'm scraping and parsing the dates to a `DateTime` object as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php).

```
foreach ($element->find('span.fechanoticia') as $fecha) {
   $tmp = str_replace("/", "-", $fecha->innertext);
   print_r($tmp);

   $dateFoo = new DateTime($tmp);
   echo $dateFoo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

   $newItem->set_fechanoticia($dateFoo);
}
```

The `$tmp` variable this value for example:

```
05-09-2012
```

The `echo` call to format returns:

```
2012-09-05 00:00:00
```

Everything is peachy, and working.

However when I try to save it to the database using RedBeanPHP I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RedBean_Exception_Security' with
> message 'Invalid Bean: property fecha ' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-uvm\rb.php:4880 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-uvm\rb.php(5108):
> RedBean_OODB->check(Object(RedBean_OODBBean)) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-uvm\rb.php(5082):
> RedBean_OODB->storeBean(Object(RedBean_OODBBean)) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-uvm\rb.php(7005):
> RedBean_OODB->store(Object(RedBean_OODBBean)) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-uvm\index.php(60):
> RedBean_Facade::store(Object(RedBean_OODBBean)) #4 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-uvm\rb.php on line 4880

Can RedBeanPHP not handle datetime objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [RedBean's documentation](http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/) (*More data types*), you can only save `DateTime` objects if they are in string form.

For example:

```
// It's a string - not a DateTime.
$photo->created = '1995-12-05 19:00:00';
```

---

In this case the solution should be to save the formatted string, not the `DateTime` object itself:

```
$newItem->set_fechanoticia($dateFoo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

found this: http://groups.google.com/group/redbeanorm/browse_thread/thread/6961ac635e6886f6

```
The Optimizer will now convert columns with datetime values to datetimefields. If a different value is inserted the column will be reverted by OODB in fluid mode.
```